# Make flex items share the same space considering all rows

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to make flex aligned items share all space, after the last item. The last (red) is a div with buttons and fixed size. Other items (blue) are *selects* and need to share the space left, considering the other rows. Other way to understand this, would be considering that the blue items need to grow after the red item, with the same width, preferably occupying all space left, but the red item needs to be always in the end of last row.

On this example I'm using flex, but I could use grid or other thing either.

Example:

[image: Example]

```
.container{
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    max-width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Please add all the code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you could do it in one line... but I know there was a possibility to automatically create a second line, if the div get too tiny. *I will update this snippet in a few minutes.*

```css
.container{
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column dense;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    background: blue;
}
.container div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.container div.red {
    width: 310px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div>MENU RANDOM</div>
      <div>MENU CONTENT</div>
      <div>MENU DIVS</div>
      <div>MENU IN</div>
      <div>MENU THIS</div>
      <div>MENU LAYOUT</div>
      <div>MENU AND</div>
      <div class="red">EXACT 210px</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```